# Is there any way to create a variable selector in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to create a variable selector in javascript or jquery?

```
var myColor1 = "#009";
var myColor2 = "#900";
var myColor1L = "#d0d"
var myColor2L = "rgb(255,100,0)";
myFunc(myColor1);
function myFunc(c){
myDiv1.style.backgroundColor = c;
myDiv2.style.backgroundColor = getVarByName(c+"L");
}
```

And the result should be that myDiv1's background color is #009,
and myDiv2's background color is #d0d.

Sorry for grammar wrongs!

Comment: `var colours = {col1:"#009",col1L:"#d0d"}, c = "col1"; alert(colours[c]); alert(colours[c+'L']);`...

Comment: The short answer is no, the alternative is what Niet just said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use an Object to store these values:

```
var colors = {
    myColor1 : "#009",
    myColor2 : "#900",
    myColor1L : "#d0d",
    myColor2L : "rgb(255,100,0)"
}

myFunc('myColor1');

function myFunc(c){
    myDiv1.style.backgroundColor = colors[c];
    myDiv2.style.backgroundColor = colors[c+"L"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window["myColor1"+"L"]
```

Comment: Unless, of course, these are *local* variables. As they should be.

Comment: have you used variable name as string??

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the name for the variable that the function was called with, because only the value of the variable is sent to the function. The value doesn't retain the name when comes to the function, it only gets the name of the parameter that it was associated with.

Instead of trying to find another variable, you can put two values in the same variable. That could be an array with two items, or an object with two properties:

```
var myColor1 = { dark: "#009", light: "#d0d" };
var myColor2 = { dark: "#900", light: "rgb(255,100,0)" };

myFunc(myColor1);

function myFunc(c){
  myDiv1.style.backgroundColor = c.dark;
  myDiv2.style.backgroundColor = c.light;
}
```

That way you don't have to name the variables in a special way. You don't even have to put the values in a variable, you can call the function with just the value:

```
myFunc({ dark: "#900", light: "#fc5" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery
var output = $("selector").css("property");

In your case it will be like
var output = $("#myDiv1").css("background")